# Web money manager for Linux

Tags: linux, web-apps, finance, self-hosted

Does anyone know a good self-hosted (Web GUI) money manager / financial tracking program for Linux? WordPress plugin, PHP project, etc.

Something similar to [Buxfer](https://www.buxfer.com/), which is great, except it is freemium.

Features required (almost same as Buxfer):

- Two or more accounts
- Option to set reccurent income / expense
- Reports Income / Expense
- Reminders
- Custom import of .csv from bank
- Open-source variant would be great
- Web UI

Comment: You need to give much more information, e.g.: Features you need, Price, etc. for this to be a good question.